# Unarchiving Apache Hudi archived commits

Tags: apache-hudi

Is it possible to unarchive an archived commit with Apache Hudi?

For example, I've set the following configuration and have 4 commits.

```
hoodie.keep.max.commits = 3

commit1
commit2
commit3
commit4
```

On the 4th commit, commit1 is archived and moved to the archive folder in s3.

```
commits_archive_1
```

Is it possible to unarchive commits_archive_1 or is it gone forever?